# desktopCapture still prompts the tab to share even after specifying the targetTab property

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, getusermedia, screen-recording

I setup the desktopCapture in the background script, and specify the current tab as the targetTab property in order to proceed to get the streamId without prompting which tab the user wants to share. But after I test the extension, it still prompts the user to select which tab screen they want to share

**background.js**:

```js
chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function(tabs) {
  const tabId = tabs[0].id;
  const currentTab = tabs[0];
  console.log(currentTab);

  // Initialize desktopCapture with the targetTab property
  chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia(
    ['tab'],
    currentTab,
    function(streamId) {
      // Create a MediaStream object for the selected tab
      if (streamId !== null || streamId != undefined) {
        sendResponse(streamId);
        console.log(streamId);
      } else {}
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: @Yogi, As mentioned earlier, tabCapture doesn't work in the backgrounds script anymore, so I am just trying to find a fix through different combinations

Answer (score 0):

The `targetTab` property doesn't specify what tab is captured. Rather, it specifies what tab *can use* the stream that is created in addition to the extension itself. For security reasons, the user will always be prompted before their screen is recorded.

The [docs for `chooseDesktopMedia`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/desktopCapture/#method-chooseDesktopMedia) explain `targetTab` as:

> Optional tab for which the stream is created. If not specified then the resulting stream can be used only by the calling extension.